# Trigger Spark Scala Job from Java Application

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am pretty new to Spark. I have created a spark job which is in Scala language. I created jar out of it and deployed it on virtual machine which is having apache spark installation in standalone mode. I want to trigger it with spark `job-server` utility from a java `main` class which is in my desktop machine. How can I do the same.